# Reset Column Values Based on Sort

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-----+------------+-----------+--------------------+
| ID  | EntityName | SortOrder | EntityCollectionId |
+-----+------------+-----------+--------------------+
| 123 | Apples     |         1 |                114 |
| 124 | Beer       |         2 |                114 |
| 125 | Chicken    |         3 |                114 |
| 126 | Tom        |         1 |                115 |
| 127 | Dick       |         2 |                115 |
| 128 | Harry      |         3 |                115 |
+-----+------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

And I am adding the following rows to this table:

```
| 129 | Apricots   |         0 |                114 |
| 130 | Bacon      |         0 |                114 |
| 131 | Cheese     |         0 |                114 |
```

Given that I now want to re-do the SortOrder for all items of EntityCollection 114 so that they are in alphabetical order by EntityName, how would I go about doing that while not touching the SortOrder of the other collections?

Comment: This seems like a value you shouldn't be storing in SQL Server and should be calculating at the point at which you query it.

Comment: Also, how can you `INSERT` the value `'Apricots'` with the ID `123`? ID `123` already exists so that would create a duplicate key error.

Comment: The example is arbitrary, and a simplified version of what is actually going on. Suffice it to say that I am unable to do the ordering at query time due to legacy stored procedures being used.

Comment: Why not fix the SP then? The problem isn't the underlying data, it's the retrieval method, and that needs to be the focus. This is a clear example of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: And/Or replace the table with a (probably updateable) view.

Comment: Look, guys, I have no ability to change the schema or stored procedures involved; the items are normally entered with a manual sort order (which is a float), but I'm looking for a method that allows me to do a massive insert and redo the sort order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an updateable cte:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        sortOrder, 
        row_number() over(partition by EntityCollectionId order by EntityName) rn
    from mytable 
    where EntityCollection = 114
)
update cte set SortOrder = n
```

Note that the `where` clause is not necessarily mandatory. If only entity collection 114 had changes, then the sort order of other records will be reassigned to the same value.

Finally: it makes little sense to store that type of information in a table. Whenever an data modification operations occurs, you need to scan the table to reassign the sort order. It seems like it would be simpler to just compute the information on the fly when you need it (typically using `row_number()` in a `select` query).

Comment: The example is a simplified version of what is actually going on, and I am unable to do the ordering at query time due to legacy stored procedures being used. If I had a choice, I'd redo the entire table structure, but that's out of my hands.